# Can't seem to be redirected

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to go to the `deleteQns.php` page from my code, but I can't seem to go there as I'm always redirected back to `administrator(Quiz2)`. I don't know what's wrong.  I hope you all will be able to help me.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php while($row=$ result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
<tr class="size">
  <form id="button" action="administrator(Quiz2).php" method="post">
    <th>
      <p>No.
        <?=$row[ "questionid"]?>
      </p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <?=$row[ "questiontext"]?>
    </th>
    <th class="editanddelete">
      <input type="hidden" name="qid" value="<?=$row[" questionid "]?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="editbtn">
  </form>
  <form id="delete" action="deleteQns.php" method="post">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Delete</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="qid" value="<?=$row[" questionid "]?>">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x;
        if (confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Question?") == true) {
          window.location = "deleteQns.php";
        } else {
          x = "";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      }
    </script>
  </form>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem occurs here:

```
window.location = "deleteQns.php";
```

You cannot be redirected because `window.location` is object with several functions for working with web protocol of the page. So when you want to change it, the best way how to do it

```
window.location.href = window.location.hostname+"/deleteQns.php";
```

For example this is equal to : `http://google.com/deleteQns.php`

You can read more about `window.location`: [MDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktv4E.png)

Another way how to check if your code doesn't work is console.

Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>

Also available through the wrench menu (Tools > JavaScript Console):

[image: JavaScript Console Menu]

(*Answer by Runscope API Tools*)

And here you can debug like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Delete</button>
<input type="hidden" name="qid" value="<?=$row[" questionid "]?>">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x;
        var confirmed = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Question?");
        /* For logging data to console */
        console.log(confirmed);
        if (confirmed == true) {
            window.location.href = window.location.hostname+"/deleteQns.php";
        } else {
            x = "";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Usually it is helpful to include some text which explains how the code answers the question or solves the problem in addition to bare code.

Comment: @Makyen answer updated and corrected, I was in a hurry